# how can I get the url of a page that opened in a different tab with puppeteer, or extract the URL from the " click here " link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```js
// this clicks on the link after page is loaded,
// there is whole process going before coming to this point.
await page.click('#ctl00_chpMain_ucContractDetails');

const url = await newPage.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
console.log(url); // this code didnt work for me.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch the tab creation event:

```js
const [url] = await Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    browser.once('targetcreated', (target) => { resolve(target.url()); });
  }),
  page.click('#ctl00_chpMain_ucContractDetails'),
]);

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thankyou, you are a life saver.! If you can spare sometime and explain how did this work, what does browser.once do and what targetcreated means, that would be great. @vsemozhebuty

Comment: @MuhammadAsadChohan You can see it in the docs in details: [event: 'targetcreated'](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated), [eventEmitter.once(event, handler)](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#eventemitteronceevent-handler). Feel free to ask if something is unclear)

Comment: @MuhammadAsadChohan Briefly: `browser.once()` is like `browser.addEventListener()` but listens for an event only once. The `'targetcreated'` event includes tab creation on a link click.

Comment: Great. thankyou. that explains a lot. <3