# How to target the selector on new tab after clicking a[target="_blank"] - Failing to activate the new tab created

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

After clicking a[target="_blank"] new tab opens. How to get code to get new page object so I can access password input field?
Using NodeJS, JavaScript, Puppeteer.

Navigation is working up to the point included below.

EDIT: I used the page.url() method to retrieve current URL and the URL of the newly created tab does not log to console, previous page logs.

I tried adjusting the script and received following errors
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'page')` - I thought adding a time delay would solve this but no go.

I was having this error but as the code is below I do not get this error: `No node found for selector: #Password`

I have looked at related issues
I came across dheerajbhaskar GitHub issue and read up on related issues

- #386
- #3535
- #978
  and more

I tried to implement code from an accepted answer without any success.
[Using Puppeteer to get a handle to the new page after "_blank" click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374443/using-puppeteer-to-get-a-handle-to-the-new-page-after-blank-click/53385453#53385453)

```js
try {
      await sleep(2300)
// This block creates a new tab 
// I was previously using a selector and not mouse click API 
      await Promise.all([
        page.mouse.click(xToolsBtn, yToolsBtn, { delay: 2000 }),
      ])
      // NEW TARGET CREATED
      // Below is a snippet from an accepted answer but the the type method 
      // does not work
      // Seems like page is still not activated
      const [newTarget] = await Promise.all([
        // Await new target to be created with the proper opener
        new Promise((x) =>
          browser.on("targetcreated", (target) => {
            if (target.opener() !== page.target()) return
            browser.removeListener("targetcreated", arguments.callee)
            x()
          })
        ),
        // page.click('link')
      ])
      // Trying to input password without success
      const newPage = await newTarget.newPage()
      await newPage.type("#Password", process.env.PASSWORD, {
        delay: randomGenerator,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(
        "LOGIN BUTTON FAIL",
        err.message
      )
    }
```

Alternatively atempt#1: I tried to select the input via mouse x, y co-ordinates which activates the input field but this returns the following error"
`No node found for selector: #Password`

Alternatively atempt#2:

```js
//* WAIT FOR TARGET
    try {
      await sleep(2300)
      await Promise.all([
        page.mouse.click(xToolsBtn, yToolsBtn, { delay: 2000 }),
      ])
      sleep(5000)
      await page.evaluate(() => window.open(`${loginUrl3}`))
      const newWindowTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(
        (target) => target.url() === `${loginUrl3}`
      )
      console.log("GOT TARGET")
      await newWindowTarget.type("#Password", process.env.PASSWORD, {
        delay: randomGenerator,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("WAIT FOR TARGET FAILED")
    }
```

Note: URLS are randomly generated so I would be curious what if any work around there is to use current URL. I would assume the new tab created would still need to be activated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

managed to solve this together (Linker :)

### Process

First, we mapped the target being created to check for focus

```
browser.on('targetcreated', function (target) {
    console.log('New tab:');
    console.log(target);
});
```

We saw the URL is trying to open - for some reason the URLs in the target were empty. We re-installed stuff to rule out weird dependency bugs, then figured there's a focus issue.

### Workaround

To solve it, we need to wait for the `.newPage()` to open before `goto`'ing to the URL, calling `bringToFront()` and then waiting for it to load (short sleep is the easy way). Once we did that, we had a working POC to start from.

Relevant part from the solution:

```
let mappedURL = tabs
  .map((e, index) => e.url())
  .filter((e, idx) => idx == 2)
console.log("MAPPED URL ", mappedURL)
sleep(2500)
const page3 = await browser.newPage()
await page3.goto(`${mappedURL}`)
await page3.bringToFront()
```

### Ref

Here's a cool SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212889/how-can-i-get-the-url-of-a-page-that-opened-in-a-different-tab-with-puppeteer-o) showing how to use `once` syntax to test the event. Happy we were able to solve it, and I hope the process helps other people out.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing just the question in the title, "How to target the selector on new tab after clicking a[target="_blank"]" -

Handling newly opened tabs in Playwright is far from intuitive if you're not used to it. A summary of how they work:

If you click a link in your test with `target="_blank"`, which opens a new tab, the `page` object you're working with *still refers to the original page/tab you opened the link on.*

To get ahold of the new page, you have to use the `context` object, which you can destructure in the test params like you do `page`, and then use the `waitForEvent('page')` method.

```js
test('my component works', async ({context, page}) => { // get the `context` object

// ...

const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    context.waitForEvent('page'), // get `context` by destructuring with `page` in the test params; 'page' is a built-in event, and **you must wait for this like this,**, or `newPage` will just be the response object, rather than an actual Playwright page object.
    page.locator('text=Click me').click() // note that, like all waiting in Playwright, this is somewhat unintuitive. This is the action which is *causing the navigation*; you have to set up the wait *before* it happens, hence the use of Promise.all().
])

 await newPage.waitForLoadState(); // wait for the new tab to fully load
 // now, use `newPage` to access the newly opened tab, rather than `page`, which will still refer to the original page/tab.
 await expect(newPage).toHaveURL('http://www.someURL.com');
 await newPage.locator('text=someText');
```